# MVC how to use firebug to check form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am submitting a form in MVC.  How do I check whether the values were submitted or correct in my form when I submit using firebug or chrome debugger?  I do not see anything in the console when I submit the page.  Is there a particular area in firebug or chrome debugger that I need to go to see the form fields and the values submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the `Net` tab of the Firebug panel or the `Network` tab of the Chrome dev tools panel.  Then select your submit request from the list to view its details.

Comment: I see it in network tab for chrome, but there is no Net tab in firebug.  I am using firebug lite for chrome.

Comment: It's only in the full Firebug, not the Lite version

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a tool such as Tamper Data, which is an add on for Firefox, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/ it will allow you to capture the POST and/or GET data from the request. (Not that you need to 'capture' GET data to be able to view it)

This is also useful if you want to test how your program handles modified POST values. How it fares if you put script or SQL in the value etc.